# Div won't clear floats

Tags: html, css

I've got an app I'm working on here: http://nicheminer.co/niche-miner.html
I've got a problem in that the main container with the class .niche-miner won't clear the floats, and you can see it's overflowing on the rest of the content.

I've used this CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

and added the class to the main container, but it still won't clear the floats.

It's driving me crazy, but for whatever reason, I can't get the main container to fully wrap the tabbed content. Any help would be much appreciated.

PS: apologies in advance for the horrible "!important" tags in the CSS - it's necessary to maintain CSS once this app gets dumped from a static page into the main site's WordPress theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
position: absolute;
```

in ***.tabs .tab-content***  causing the issue.

Changing it to

```
position: relative;
```

will solve the "clear" issue, However you have to make necessary css adjustments to make the layout looks like before.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.tabs .tab-content` rule is setting `position: absolute;` on each `.tab-content`, thus taking them out of the document flow.